# Update dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I think this will be a simple answer and I'm just missing something.  I have a list which contains several dictionaries.  So for a simplified example the data structure is this:

```
acctList = [{'acctid' : '101'},{'acctid' : '102'}, {'acctid' : '103'}]
```

I want update the dictionaries in the list with a new value.  but when I do something like this:

```
acctList[0].update({'acctid' : 'aaa'})
```

ALL of the dictionaries in the list get updated with the new value instead of just the one at index 0.  I know that lists also use update, so I'm not sure how to specify I'm trying to update the dictionary and not the list item.  Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you *create* `acctList`? You appear to have a list of 3 references, all to the same single dictionary object. This is usually an indication you didn't create new dictionary objects when creating the list.

Comment: Probably the wrong way.  I used acctList.append inside a while loop to increment the counter and insert new data.

Comment: You need to create *new* dictionary objects there. If you are reusing one dictionary object, create a copy with `dictobj.copy()`. Can you post your `while` loop please?

Comment: Open an interpreter, then execute two lines you wrote above. The result is not like you claim. There is nothing wrong with these lines.

Comment: @dirtybit: which is why we are asking for that `while` loop..

Comment: while x <= 18:
  bodyList.append(body)
  x += 1  
that's it.  Body is passed into the function.  I make 18 copies of it and then I need to update the copies to different values.  I reread what I gave you guys and it wasn't the best description (santization on the fly didn't help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your dictionaries so that you have a unique dictionary in each index of the list, e.g.:

```
acctList = [dict(acctid=str(i)) for i in range(101, 104)]
```

and acctList is:

```
[{'acctid' : '101'},{'acctid' : '102'}, {'acctid' : '103'}]
```

Then you can modify each one separately without affecting the others:

```
>>> acctList[0].update(dict(acctid='10101'))
>>> acctList
[{'acctid': '10101'}, {'acctid': '102'}, {'acctid': '103'}]
```

Explanation:

When you create a list where every index points to the same object, and that object is mutable, changing in one place affects the rest because they're all the same object:

```
>>> l = [[]]*4
>>> l[0].append('foo')
>>> l
[['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo']]
```

Since integers are immutable, you can do the following:

```
>>> l = [0]*4
>>> l
[0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> l[0]+=1
>>> l
[1, 0, 0, 0]
```

In Python, mutable objects are sometimes used to hold and increment on integers when you need a pointer that can't change, and so you can't use a plain integer.

Comment: Yes, I give a more in-depth explanation now.

Comment: Yup, this is the issue.  I am going to work around it.